# Asymmetry of functions defined on the $n$-th roots of the unity

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{V : \mathbb{U}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\}$ where $\mathbb{U}_n$ is the group of the complex $n$-th roots of the unity. This group naturally acts on $\mathcal{A}$: for any $a \in \mathbb{U}_n$, and any $V \in \mathcal{A}$
$$
  \begin{equation*}
    (a \star V) : b \mapsto V(a^{-1}b)
  \end{equation*}
$$
I define $Fix(V) = \{a \in \mathbb{U}_n,~ a \star V = V\}$ the symmetry group of $V$.

My question is: can we define an equivariant function $\lambda : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which measures the "asymmetry" of $V$, i.e., a function such that for all $a,V$
$$
  \begin{align*}
     \lambda(a \star V) &= a \lambda(V) \\
     \lambda(V) = 0 &\Leftrightarrow Fix(V) \neq \{1\}
  \end{align*}
$$

Is it related to some known problem ? Satisfying the first condition is ok, for instance
$$
  \begin{equation*}
    \lambda_0(V) = \sum_{z \in \mathbb{U}_n} z V(z)
  \end{equation*}
$$
but the second condition is not ok. Indeed, it suffices to take $V$ as the indicator function of, say, the union of a triangle and a square (in a suitable $\mathbb{U}_n$). The sum above is zero but this $V$ has a trivial symmetry group.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a typo? Do you mean $\lambda(V)=0 \Leftrightarrow Fix(V)\ne \{1\}$? The condition $Fix(V)\ne \{1\}$ at least implies $\lambda(V)=0$ under your equivariance assumption.

Comment: You're right, I updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you require $\lambda$ to be linear?

Comment: No, only the equivariance and the "asymmetry detection" are required. But I guess we could also look for  a $\lambda$ taking values in something more intricate than $\mathbb{C}$ ...

Comment: Small remark: if $n$ is prime then I think Fix(V) is non-trivial iff it is the whole group iff V is constant, so you could take $\lambda(V)$ to be the variance of $V$. In general, would you be happy for $\lambda$ to depend on the arithmetic properties of $n$?

Comment: I had in mind a composite number. But I think your proposition does not match the equivariance, does it?